# Convergence in probability of $X_n\sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(1,\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Maybe you can help me with the following task. I still have a lot of problems with convergence of random variable.
Let $X_n$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$  independent random variables on $(\Omega,F,P)$ with $P_{X_n}=\operatorname{Bin}\left(1,\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

a) Show that $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$.

Therefore I have to that $$\lim_{n\to0}P[\vert X_n-X\vert\geq\varepsilon]=0$$

So $\lim_{n\to0}P[\vert X_n\vert\geq\varepsilon]=0$ and now I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Since $X_n$ is discrete you just want to show that $$\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-\frac1n\to1$$as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Can u explain me, how this follows from the definition?

Comment: What is the definition of $Bin(1,\frac 1n)$ you are working with?

Comment: Bin(n,p) n is the number of tries and p the probability or did u mean something different?

Comment: Right, and since $n=1$ in this case you can write out explicitly the probability that $X_n$ takes each value.  I think writing that out will help you to see what @PeterForeman did in his comment.

Comment: So because $n=1$ $X$ can only be $0$ if we have no success in a sequence of $n=1$ and thats is $\binom{1}{k}(\frac{1}{n})^k(1-\frac{1}{n})^{1-k}$ with $k=0$ or $X$ equals $1$ if we have one success in a sequence of $n=1$ then we have  $\binom{1}{k}(\frac{1}{n})^k(1-\frac{1}{n})^{1-k}$ with $k=1$?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  And you can simplify those expressions a lot by plugging in $k=0$ and $k=1$ since you know $a^0 = 1$ for all $a$.

Comment: If i simplify it I have$P(X_n=0)= 1-\frac{1}{n} \to 1$and $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and because the probability of $P(X_n=0)=1$ $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it!

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you mean by $P_{X_n} = Bin(1,\frac{1}{n})$ is that $P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.

Therefore, if $\epsilon > 1$, we know that $P(|X_n-0| \geq 1) = 0$, since $X_n\in \{0,1\}$.

Now, if $0<\epsilon \leq 1$, then $P(|X_n -0|\geq\epsilon) = P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n}$. It is now easy to see that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|X_n -0|\geq\epsilon) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$

Comment: yes thanks :) you wrote up my ideas above in a mathematical way :)

Comment: @WalterFrosch Do you not want to accept $\left( \color{\limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$ the answer?